# Background images for mobile apps

Tags: android, mobile, ionic-framework

I use Ionic for making a hybrid application. I have read the documentation regarding setting background images for different devices, but I was wondering if it is better to use device resolution or pixel density values for setting background images?

Answer (score 0):

If we want a background img we put it inside a  or a  for example, and put the following styles in css:

```
.img-class-name{
      background: url("../img/path/to/your.jpg") center;
      background-size: cover;
}
```

our images are in the default folder:

[image]

This has worked fine for all our needs.